# Putting the value of selected color on colorpicker to the textfield.color property?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Im having trouble changing the font color of a textfield. Its tricky cause its not just simply a textfield cause its in a movieclip or converted to a sprite.

```
import flash.display.MovieClip 
import flash.text.TextField 
import flash.text.TextFormat 
import flash.text.TextFieldType 
import flash.events.MouseEvent 

var mc:MovieClip=new MovieClip() 
var txtField:TextField=new TextField() 
addChild(mc) 

mc.x=470; 
mc.y=325 

var txtFormat:TextFormat=new TextFormat() 
txtFormat.color=0xFF0000
txtFormat.font="Verdana" 
txtFormat.bold=false 
txtFormat.size=30 
txtFormat.align=TextFormatAlign.CENTER 

txtField.type=TextFieldType.INPUT 
txtField.border=true 
txtField.background=true 
txtField.width=350
txtField.height=50 
txtField.wordWrap=true 
txtField.defaultTextFormat=txtFormat 

mc.addChild(txtField)
```

Im using the colorpicker component. how do i call the colorpicker.selectedcolor and put it in this part:

txtFormat.color=0xFF0000

Theres another way where i can just put simply an input text and NOT any confusing addchild thing. BUT i dont know how to change the textcolor of the INPUT TEXT.

Answer (score 0):

The [`TextField`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html) class has a [`textColor`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#textColor) property.